# Update un registro "cantidad" JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy practicando hacer un sistema de venta de bebidas, en el cual tengo una tabla con los productos, con un boton para agregar al carrito. 
Si el producto seleccionado YA ESTA en el carrito, solo incrementa en 1 la CANTIDAD del mismo.  Sino, lo añade a la lista y le coloca cantidad 1.

la entidad Compra tiene un constructor con 3 parametros (Str producto, int precio, int cantidad). y opera con una tabla aparte en la BD llamada ESTA_COMPRA con los mismos campos en ella.

Con el codigo que tengo ahora me esta tirando:

> "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 Argumento incorrecto en una llamada JDBC: parameter index out of range: 3
>       at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessPreparedStatement.setInt(UcanaccessPreparedStatement.java:536)
>       at sistemaventasbebidas.DAO.update_Cantidad(DAO.java:141)
>       at sistemaventasbebidas.VistaController.agregarCarro2(VistaController.java:205)"

No se porque me tira outofbond(3) si 3 es el numero del registro Cantidad en la BD.

Tengo en el DAO:

```
/////////update cantidad en DB esta_compra///////////
public void update_Cantidad(entidad_Compras ec){
   DBCon conec = new DBCon();
   String sql= "UPDATE ESTA_COMPRA SET  cantidad=?" + "WHERE producto=?";
    PreparedStatement ps = null; 
    try {
            ps = conec.Connect().prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(3, ec.getCantidad());
            ps.executeUpdate();



        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}
```

y en el controller:

```
@FXML
private void agregarCarro2(){

if (! tabla_bebidas.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()){
    entidad_Bebidas bebida = tabla_bebidas.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();    
String produ = tproducto.getText();
int precio = Integer.parseInt(tprecio.getText());      // seteo los 3 parametros para ingresarle al objeto EC
//cantidad = cantidad + 1;

//stock   aca faltaria una funcion para ir actualizando el stock en la bd, pero que pueda volver a la normalidad en caso de cancelar la compra.
if (Integer.parseInt(tstock.getText())> 0){
int stockinicial = bebida.getStock();
int stockactual = Integer.parseInt(tstock.getText());
int nuevoStock = stockactual - 1;
tstock.setText(String.valueOf(nuevoStock));
} else{
   lblStock.setVisible(true);  
}
////////

//precio
total =total +  precio;
tTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
//


DAO dao = new DAO();
entidad_Compras ec = new entidad_Compras(produ,precio,cantidad);
if (dao.esta_En_Carrito(produ)){
    ec.setCantidad(ec.getCantidad() + 1);
    dao.update_Cantidad(ec); //si esta en el carrito suma cantidad
    loadTablaCompras();
}else{
    //insertar compra en la bd
    ec.setCantidad(1);
    dao.Agregar_Producto_Carrito(ec);
    dao.update_Cantidad(ec);
    loadTablaCompras();
}
}//tablabebidas

}//agregar carrito 2
```

No estoy 100% seguro de lo que hago jaja.  Estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta!
Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: a ese prepare statement no le falta un parametro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error que te arroja es porque tenes que indicarle el numero de parametro, en este caso debe ir 1 y no 3 para cantidad y adicionalmente habra que especificar otro para producto, yo puse setInt (a modo de ejemplo para producto)pero este dependerá del tipo de dato del codigo de producto en tu caso. Es necesario especificar estos dos parametros ya que tu query asi lo requiere

```
 ps = conec.Connect().prepareStatement(sql);
 ps.setInt(1, ec.getCantidad());   
 ps.setInt(2,datoproducto)
 ps.executeUpdate();
```

Tu consulta requiere dos parametros, por eso el error

```
String sql= "UPDATE ESTA_COMPRA SET  cantidad=?" + "WHERE producto=?";
```

Esta es una buena referencia https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Excelente! Ahora lo pruebo para ya entendì porque el error :D

Comment: Ok @Gabriel Mc Gann , acordate de aceptar la respuesta si te sirvio. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Hecho! mil gracias a vos! ya no tira el error, si bien no me suma la cantidad (Simpre es 1) pero no importa, debe ser alguna tontera logica mia jaja.  Mil gracias